Pycharm throws error SystemError: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault when debugging
Problem: PyCharm debugger won't stop on breakpoints and quits unexpectedly with SystemError: _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault This appears in the log/debug window
I searched all around for this but couldn't find any solutions. My answer will follow below.

This is caused by a broken installation of the Cython accelerators. Removing them should cause PyCharm to prompt to re-install them. After doing this, the problem will be fixed. In Linux, the accelerator folder is ~/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2024.1/cythonExtensions/. Just delete that folder.
